# Unemployment benefits coding in U.S. SIPP data

Tags: usa, us-census, census

I'm having a good deal of trouble navigating the data dictionary for variables in the U.S. Census Survey of Income and Program Participation (SIPP). Here's a specific puzzle I've been unable to solve:

I'm looking for data on an individual's receipt of unemployment benefits. However, there are at least two different variables with the same label in the core wave files:

```
euectyp5        byte   %15.0g      euectypm   GI: Receipt of State unemployment comp.
er05            byte   %15.0g      er05l      GI: Receipt of State Unemployment Comp.
```

And the variables do not have equivalent values:

```
. ta euectyp5 er05, mi

 GI: Receipt of |
          State |       GI: Receipt of State
   unemployment |     Unemployment Comp. (ISS
     comp. (ISS | Not in Un        Yes         No |     Total
----------------+---------------------------------+----------
Not in Universe |   416,059          0          0 |   416,059 
            Yes |         0      3,746      1,790 |     5,536 
             No |       316          0          0 |       316 
----------------+---------------------------------+----------
          Total |   416,375      3,746      1,790 |   421,911
```

(This is all from 2008 Panel, Wave 1, but appears to be true in other waves as well. Have not checked other panels.)

The only thing I can think to do is to cross-reference with the questionnaire to determine what each question was actually asking, but the questionnaire itself (as downloaded [here](http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/sipp/data/2008-panel/wave-1.html)) does not actually have these variable names in the file. I started trying to read the 400-page questionnaire to deduce where each were coming from, but this was unsuccessful, not to mention unbearably tedious because the questions are full of stuff like `[fill OTHSRCE_ARR(<33>):l](33)` and other such macros that it is hard to track down the meaning of.

What am I missing? What is the difference between these variables: and, more generally, how do I go about figuring out other such puzzles when the variable names do not actually match those in the questionnaire and the questionnaire is so hard to read?

**UPDATE:**

I also wrote the census, as Albert recommended. they wrote back immediately and very helpfully. Here is the complete response:

> The structure of the EUECTYP5 and ER05 variables can be confusing.
>
> EUECTYP5 covers the entire reference period.  So, respondents who have
>   a 1 in this field have received state unemployment compensation at
>   some point during the four-month reference period.
>
> You can see this in the question for EUECTYP5 on page 7-189, from the
>   data dictionary, SIPP 2008 Panel Waves 01-10 - Core Data Dictionary,
>   available here: 
>   http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/sipp/tech-documentation/data-dictionaries/data-dictionaries-2008.html
>   Did ... receive any state unemployment compensation during the
>   reference period?
>
> ER05, however, is a monthly variable.  So, it records receipt or
>   non-receipt in each month.  It appears on page 7-229 of that same data
>   dictionary.  Did ... receive income from State unemployment
>   compensation in this month.
>
> Usually, you could also see this in the universe statements, but
>   unfortunately, there is an error in the EUECTYP5 universe statement
>   posted in the data dictionary.  It should read All persons 15+ at the
>   end of the reference period.
>
> The ER05 universe, however, is correct as posted: All persons 15+ at
>   the end of the reference period indicating receipt of State
>   unemployment compensation sometime during the reference period.
>   (EUECTYP5 = 1)
>
> So, the ER05 recipients are a subset of EUECTYP5 recipients. 
>   Respondents who received unemployment compensation in all 4 months of
>   the reference period will have a "1" for both ER05 and EUECTYP5 in all
>   4 months of a wave.  But, respondents who only received UC in one
>   month will have ER05 and EUECTYP5 = 1 in that month, and will have
>   EUECTYP5=1 and ER05=2 in the other 3 months of the wave.
>
> As far as trying to figure out variable names from question fields, it
>   really depends on the variable you are looking at and the section in
>   which it appears.  For some fields there is a pretty easy one-to-one
>   correspondence between the variable and the relevant question.  For
>   others, however, it isn't as clear what the connection is.
>
> I suggest looking at the user's guide, data dictionary, and user's
>   notes, as you have been doing, and then writing in with questions. 
>   We're happy to help in whatever way we can.

Comment: did you contact the census?

Comment: Not yet. Figured I was probably missing something obvious and/or that I would get a faster better response here.

Comment: the sipp 2008 panel reference periods are four months.  one month means one month, reference period means four months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/sipp/2008/l08w11d.txt

```
D EUECTYP5    2   1209
T GI: Receipt of State unemployment comp. (ISS 
  Code 5)
     Did ... receive any state unemployment 
     compensation during the reference period?  
U All persons aged 15+ at end of reference period 
   who indicated receipt of unemployment 
  compensation  income since the beginning of 
  the reference period.  (EPOPSTAT = 1) 
V         -1 .Not in Universe
V          1 .Yes
V          2 .No


D ER05        2   1479
T GI: Receipt of State Unemployment Comp. (ISS 
  Code 5)
     Did ... receive income from State 
     unemployment compensation in this month. 
     ISS Code 5   
U All persons 15+ at the end of the reference 
  period indicating  receipt of State 
  unemployment compensation sometime during the 
   reference period. (EUECTYP5 = 1) 
V         -1 .Not in Universe
V          1 .Yes
V          2 .No
```